# Unable to Track Click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to send an event to **google analytics** whenever the user clicks on the minimize icon on my chat box.

The minimize icon has the `id #minimize`, i am simply starting with a a console log hello  when clicked, but i can not figure out why it's not working.

The site is: http://2.internetremovals.com.au/
You can see the chat box in the bottom right corner.

My script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery( "#minimize" ).click(function() {
      console.log("hello");
   });
</script>
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions anyone can spare :]

Comment: there is a file not found error for `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://chatsystem.io/208680"></script>`

Comment: jQuery( "#minimize" ) do not find any element.

Comment: Make sure there is no other script error. Any script error which are being executed before this script ,will stop all script excution

Comment: You've got GTM on the site, so you could track the event through that and not worry about coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change you code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $( "#minimize" ).click(function() {
        console.log("hello");
    });
});
```

or try this

```
$.getScript("https://chatsystem.io/208680", function() {
    console.log("hello 1!")
        $(document).on('click', "#minimize", function() {
    console.log("hello 2!")
    });
});
```

This will bind event after chatbox loaded

This need to ensure that all other stuff loaded before you code begin to work!

UPDATE 1

Added new code

Comment: Thanks for all the answers everyone,
Vasilij is correct, your syntax is correct. I believe i can't track the #minimize element as it is loaded onto the page by a third party (leadchat.io).
If i swap minimize with #logo, it works perfectly.
Any idea how i might track the elements making up the leadchat.io box? 
Thanks!

Comment: Try to add code `$( "#minimize" ).click(function() {
        console.log("hello");
    });` to code that loads to you  info from (leadchat.io), so it must add event after all third party code loads and all elements injected into you page.

Comment: Ahhh i'm afraid that was my first plan of attack Vasilij, however i am unable to add any code to the leadchat.io, (it isn't even a plug in, very frustrating),
Is there anyway i can write a script that says "once everything is loaded, do X" ? - but then again, would this even affect the leadchat.io? thanks Vasilij!

Comment: Can you post you code that get data from leadchat.io ?

Comment: From my understanding, i can't see any code which loads the leadchat.io, its as if it is loaded by a third company, on top of the site. As if the leadchat company can tell when the site is loaded, and loads the leadchat.io over the top... the site is: http://2.internetremovals.com.au/ - would you agree the box is loaded independently? (i possess very basic coding skills...:( )

Comment: It seems you have error in this string `<!-- Start Chatsystem.io Code --> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://chatsystem.io/208680"></script> <!-- EndChatsystem.io Code --<link rel='styles` replace this `Code --<` with `Code --><`

Comment: I update my anwser, it not works in fiddle, but i hope it helps and works for you

Comment: Just thought i'd let you know that i worked out another way, using GTM, i have found a lovely guide detailing how to accomplish a solution to my problem.
http://leadchat.helpscoutdocs.com/article/69-setting-up-google-tag-manager-for-conversion-tracking
Thanks very much Vasilij!